# Apache Spark: How to extract only common records from a database to cluster

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have "100k records" on my cluster and "100million records" in a Database(eg:MySql).

How can I get only common records between these two datasets into a "dataFrame" or "RDD" without physically moving the entire 100 million records into the cluster?

These "100 million records" may increase everyday. So just to compare it with a small dataset of "100k" I don't want to move the entire large dataset from the database.

Does "mapPartitions" play any role here?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to follow the below process.

1. Export the 100k records table to RDBMS staging table using spark jdbc
2. Import the data back using spark jdbc ,  for spark jdbc send the join query.

   - With this approch database engine itself filter data and will send only common records.
     -However, data sources such as SQL Engines are capable of doing even more preprocessing, e.g., evaluating aggregates. This is beneficial because it would reduce the amount of data transferred from the source to Spark. The existing interfaces do not allow such kind of processing in the source.   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12449
   - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20259